Npm install stuck in AWS for React application
I have tried to deploy my React application in AWS. I chose t2.micro instance type. While doing npm install -f, installation getting stuck in same place for multiple time. I tried multiple instance (t2. micro) but issue still persist. Can someone suggest what actually went wrong?

